# Can i define User Defined key at info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone

Can i defined a user defined key with given name "SomeKey" and can i access with  `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"SomeKey"]`

Comment: Yes, you can. for [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW10)

Answer (score 11):

Of course!

**Apple Docs**:

> **Custom Keys**
>
> iOS and macOS ignore custom keys you include in an Info.plist file. If
>   you want to include app-specific configuration information in your
>   Info.plist file, you can do so freely as long as your key names do not
>   conflict with the ones Apple uses. When defining custom key names,
>   prefix them with a unique prefix, such as your app’s bundle ID or your
>   company’s domain name, to prevent conflicts.

And you can get the value by doing something like this:

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

or

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

**Swift**

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["SomeKey"]
```

**Reference:**

[Info Plist Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1)

[Reserved Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW10)

Comment: modern objective-C:

    NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"SomeKey"]

Answer (score 5):

We do access the application bundle info.plist like shown below,

> Objective-C

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *appDisplayName = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

> Swift

```
let appDisplayName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

Similarly, If you have added any custom key-value pair in the info.plist you can surely access it. Just replace the CFBundleDisplayName with your key.

[Refere this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1)

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: Yes.

Read: Custom Keys in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW10)